# IIS, impact of disabling request limit queue

Tags: iis-6

[image]

What are the implications of disabling the "Limit the Kernel request queue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you removed the limit your server will queue unlimited number of requests until the server runs out of memory which obviously never good!

Microsoft recommend that the limit is never removed on a production server which I believe is good advice.

*Edit, it's helpful if you accept peoples answers...